# Generic circuit for signature matrix

Tags: circuit-construction, grovers-algorithm, matrix-representation

Consider a set $ A = \{a_0,a_2,\ldots,a_{k-1}\} \subset [N] := \{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$.

Consider the diagonal matrix
\begin{equation}
R := I - 2 \sum_{a\in A} |a\rangle\langle a|,
\end{equation}
which is just a Grover reflection.

Given knowledge of $A$, and access to controlled Z and rotations, what is the optimal sequence of operations to implement $R$?

Comment: By optimal sequence, do you mean circuit with least depth? Then it depends on the gateset you have.

Comment: Good question, let's say we have access to controlled Z and arbitrary rotation, I think that should be sufficient